# Question about Conceptual Understanding for Circular doubly linked list in Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am a beginner coder in java and in general and I wanted to ask for some help. I am doing an assignment in which I am supposed to make a `CircularLinkedList` which is like a `DoublyLinkedList`. But for `CircularLinkedList` am not allowed to have a head or a tail. Instead, I have a pointer to one of the nodes in the `CircularLinkedList`. So, to my understanding from basic `LinkedList`, the head node is where we would implement our series of Singly `LinkedList`.

I have made a `DoubleNode` pointer as a global variable that will at first point at the first node when we create a circular linked list. when I construct a `CircularLinkedList` that is empty.

My question is: Should this `DoubleNode` pointer point to null within the constructor or should I just create a new node and make them point to null with not value to claim its empty?

I am posting my code for better understanding my concept

```
public class CircularLinkedList<T> {

    DoubleNode pointer; //create a double node of pointer [/| no data |\]
    int lengthoflinkedlist = 0;

    private class DoubleNode<T> { //create a DoubleNode class to understand how nodes would look in the circular linked list
        private DoubleNode prev;
        private T data;
        private DoubleNode next;

        // Now we input our functions into the class or methods as they call it
        public DoubleNode(){ //constructors for bas node.
            this.prev = null;
            this.next = null;
        }

        public DoubleNode(T data) {
            this.prev = null;
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }

        public DoubleNode(DoubleNode P, T data, DoubleNode N){
            this.prev = P;
            this.data = data;
            this.next = N;
        }
    }

    public CircularLinkedList() {
        // pointer
        DoubleNode A = new DoubleNode(); // creates a node with nothing and pointers to null;
    }

    public CircularLinkedList(int initSize, T initValue) { //constucting a circular linked list
        // TODO implement me
        //initSize means the size of linkedlist
        //initValue means the value of data T in the nodes.

        if(initSize == 0) { //throw error as length 0 means linkedlist is empty
            System.out.println("The linked list with size 0 means it is an empty linkedlist with a Pointer pointing to Nothing");

        }
        else {
            DoubleNode check = this.pointer;
            for(int lengthoflinkedlist = 0; lengthoflinkedlist < initSize - 1; lengthoflinkedlist++) {
                DoubleNode A = new DoubleNode(this.pointer.next,initValue,this.pointer.prev);
            }
        }
    }

    public void moveForward() {
        // TODO implement me
    }

    public void moveBackward() {
        // TODO implement me
    }

    public T getValue() {
        // TODO implement me
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @return the previous value of the updated node
     */
    public T setValue(T value) {
        // TODO implement me
        return null;
    }

    public void addBefore(T value) {
        // TODO implement me
    }

    public void addAfter(T value) {
        // TODO implement me
    }

    /**
     * @return the previous value of the removed node
     */
    public T removeBefore() {
        // TODO implement me
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @return the previous value of the removed node
     */
    public T removeAfter() {
        // TODO implement me
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO implement me
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am still implementing my class and constructors atm so i need help based on that

Comment: An empty list should have no node.

Comment: Yes. i have made my instance of Doublenode Pointer to Null; as it has nothing, an empty circular linkedlist.

Comment: Maybe the ["Standard implementation"(jdk8)](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java) can guide you/offer valueable insights. (Or "drill down" (with your IDE) into `java.util.LinkedList`;)

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, first of, I have made a DoubleNode pointer as a global variable that will at first point at the first node when we create a circular linked list.

I can't see a "global" variable.  I can see an instance variable called `pointer` ... which I assume is what you are talking about.

> Should this DoubleNode pointer point to null within the constructor or should I just create a new node and make them point to null with not value to claim its empty?

Actually, you can do it either way.

- One way would be to have an empty list represented as a `CircularLinkedList` with a `null` value in the `pointer` field.
- Another way would be to have an empty list represented as a `CircularLinkedList` with a `pointer` that refers to a `DoubleNode` with `null` data.

I think that the first approach will be simpler.  Either way you need special case code for when the list is empty.

Comment: so this is what i did for constructor with empty circular linked list.                                          ***public CircularLinkedList() { //points back to itself.
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  // pointer
   DoubleNode A = new DoubleNode(); // creates a node with nothing and pointers to null;
   this.pointer = A; // here we initialize the pointer to point to A like this [][][] -> [/][null][/]
   pointer.next = A;
   pointer.prev = A;
//   System.out.println(A.data);
   A.next = pointer.prev;
   A.prev = pointer.next;
//   System.out.println(A.next.data);
 }

Comment: The `A` variable is local to the constructor.  It disappears when the constructor returns

Comment: oh yes. i know about that. what i did here was i created a new node in circular linked list constructor which i am not supposed to do. what i did now is that since it wants me to create an Empty circular linked list meaning that it is pointing to nothing. so this is literally what i did *** public CircularLinkedList() { //points back to itself.
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  // pointer
   this.pointer = null; //the pointer will just point to null as it points to nothing.

Comment: Well if you refer back to my answer, I said that one alternative representation of an empty list is to set `pointer` to `null`.  So then operations on a circular list would *test* to see if `pointer` is `null` or not, and handle case appropriately.

Comment: yes thank you for that. it made sense to me after drawing out what empty really means

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> But for `CircularLinkedList` am not allowed to have a head or a tail.

I would expect this to be true since a circle doesn't have a concrete beginning or end. In a circle, they are arbitrary. Unlike a conventional list, when a circular list is empty, the head (beginning node) is whatever you want it to be. The trick is how you calculate the end. This is important because at some point you need to calculate if the circular list is full.

[image]

Assume this array is your "circular list". You could literally decide to make your first insertion right in the middle (index 2). In this case, the "tail" will be your starting index minus 1 (i.e. 1). The problem is, how do you wrap around when you reach index 4 to go to index 0 for the next insertion?

To increment an index in a wrap around manner, you need to use the following formula: `index = (index + 1) % N` where `N` is the size of the list; in this case 5.

Now, how do you know your circular list is full? This is actually pretty simple. Before you insert, you will "peek" to the next location to see if there is something there already. If the next slot in your circular list is empty, you can then insert. ON the other hand, if the next slot is full, your list is full.

Last, you need to consider going in reverse order (i.e. to get previous node). The technique is the same. First, you will "peek" the previous index to see if there something there. If the previous slot has a node, you can freely do what you need with it.

The rest of things to considered are unknown to me because your post is not very specific.